# how to change text of nested html element using asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm new to web techs. I have a bunch of elements nested in each other. I want to change some of them's texts using asp.net neither jquery nor javascript. Firstly, I need to select that element by code. Then I need to assign new text value to it.

Here's my HTML.

```
<div class="container">
            <article class="card">
                <img runat="server" id="foodImage" src="/pics/food/dolma.jpg" alt="Sample Photo" />
                <div class="mealInfo">
                    <span class="left"><a id="foodAnchor" runat="server" href="#">Dolma Yemeği</a><br />
                        <span class="prepInfo">For 6-8 people Prep time 2 hours</span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="right"><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i>
                        <br />
                        385</span>
                </div>
                <div class="cookInfo">
                    <a class="cookName" href="#"><img src="/pics/ppic.jpg"/>electricianSmurf</a>
                    <a class="comment" href="#"><i class="far fa-comment"></i>5</a>
                </div>
            </article>
</div>
```

Here's my ASP code. I want to dynamically change foodImage's image and foodAnchor's text. I can get those elements using their IDs but there are 8 more "card" articles(they're used as flexbox). I want to reach all of them with code and change them according to the data coming from the database(ignore this database part, firstly I need to bring elements with code)
This is a coined code represents what I want to do. Please help.

```
 List<anchorText's type or anchor type> anchorList = new List<anchorText's type or anchor type>;
    for (int i = 0; i < anchorList.Count; i++)
    {
        Control targetElement = FindControl("card #foodImage mealInfo left a");
        if (targetElement != null)
        {
            anchorList.Add(targetElement);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < anchorList.Count; i++)
    {
        anchorList[i].Text = textComingFromDatabase;
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest putting the one template in a repeater, and then data binding that repeater. It will automatic repeat for you, and you not have to run a loop to inject the text - the repeater will do that for you.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Is it possible to get elements by their tag and then put them into a list? such as; in JS there's a code getElementsByTagName or class. Is it possible to make it in asp.net? I just want to put some specific elements into a list and then I want to change their texts.

Comment: if you give the control in quesiton a "ID" and runat="server", then you can in most cases directly change the value in code behind. It not 100% clear why a span is being used say as opposed as a label or text box - but yes, you can add both "ID" and runat="server". You now note in code behind then MySpan.InnerText, or MySpan.InnHTML can directly be used to set such values with code-behind.